# Add namespace to specific root element using xslt 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

How to convert the given xml to the target one as given below.
I try to achieve this in xlst but it add namespace to "Envelope" instead of "ServiceResponse"

Source xml -

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <ServiceResponse xmlns="http://www.scym.com/abcd/dmb/Service/v1">
         <RelatedCFR>
            <NUMBER>481511</NUMBER>
            <CATEGORY>TECHNICAL/BUSINESS APPROVAL</CATEGORY>
            <CURRENT_PHASE>CFR PIR/A</CURRENT_PHASE>
            <BRIEF_DESCRIPTION>Description Here</BRIEF_DESCRIPTION>
         </RelatedCFR>
      </ServiceResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Needs to be transformed as follows -

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <ns2:ServiceResponse xmlns:ns2="http://www.scym.com/abcd/dmb/Service/v1">
         <RelatedCFR>
            <NUMBER>481511</NUMBER>
            <CATEGORY>TECHNICAL/BUSINESS APPROVAL</CATEGORY>
            <CURRENT_PHASE>CFR PIR/A</CURRENT_PHASE>
            <BRIEF_DESCRIPTION>Description Here</BRIEF_DESCRIPTION>
         </RelatedCFR>
      </ns2:ServiceResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I tried below xlst its not working

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="@*|text()|comment()|processing-instruction()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/ServiceResponse">
        <ns2:ServiceResponse xmlns:ns2="http://www.scym.com/abcd/dmb/Service/v1">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </ns2:ServiceResponse>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace="http://www.scym.com/abcd/dmb/Service/v1">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, this isn't "adding a namespace", it is changing the names of the elements. For example you are changing the name of the `CATEGORY` element from `Q{http://www.scym.com/abcd/dmb/Service/v1}CATEGORY` to `Q{}CATEGORY`.

(I'm using the notation `Q{namespace}local-part` from XPath 3.0 here).

You actually seem to have grasped that you are changing the names in the way you have written the `match='*'` template rule, but you are changing the names of elements such as `CATEGORY` to be in namespace `http://www.scym.com/abcd/dmb/Service/v1` when your desired XML output indicates that they should be in no namespace.

Your template rule with `match="/ServiceResponse"` will only match a ServiceResponse element that is (a) the outermost element of the document, and (b) in no namespace. To match the `ServiceResponse` in your example input, use

`match="x:ServiceResponse" xmlns:x="http://www.scym.com/abcd/dmb/Service/v1"`